# Full Width Header in Magento with Skeleton

Tags: html, css, magento, layout, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am creating a website in Magento and am trying to implement the latest skeleton boilerplate but am having trouble giving the whole page a max width of 960px.

I have been following the [fantastic LevelUp Tuts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6jeQFtxIYPA&index=40&list=PL3B0BAAF482B16EAB)! tutorials keeping in mind that he is using the older skeleton boilerplate.

The tutorial advises to give the div with a class of wrapper a class of container.

Doing so however limits the header to 960px but the page retains a width of 1414 an consequently the header does not occupy the full page.

How can I make sure the header and footer occupy the full width of the page whilst sticking to the skeleton grid system with a max width of 960px?

Here is my layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
    <div class="page">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
        <div class="main-container col2-left-layout container clearfix">
            <div class="main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                <section class="col-main ten columns">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                </section>
                <aside class="col-left sidebar two columns"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></aside>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_cookie_notice') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my css:

```
/*
  ========================================
  Skeleton reponsive grid
  ========================================
*/
@import url('normalize.css');
@import url('skeleton.css');

/*
  ========================================
  Custom styles
  ========================================
*/

/*
  ========================================
  Sidebar
  ========================================
*/

.col-left {
    background: gray;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Header
  ========================================
*/
.main-header {
    padding: 40px 0 20px 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.header-container {
    background-color: #80BFFF;
}

/*
Quick access links
*/
.quick-access .links li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 2px;
}
.quick-access .links li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none; 
    }
.quick-access .links li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/*
  ========================================
Search box
  ========================================
*/
.quick-access .form-search label {
    display: none;
}
.quick-access .form-search input.input-text {
    display: inline;
}

/*
Welcome message
*/

.welcome-msg {
    color: white;
}
```

My HTML for Header:

```
<div class="header-container">
    <header class="container main-header">
        <?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
        <h1 class="logo three columns alpha"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
        </h1>
        <?php else:?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo three columns alpha"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
        <?php endif?>
    <div class="quick-access five columns offset-by-four omega">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topcart'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
    </div>
    <h3 class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></h3>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>
    </header>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
```

Comment: I've used skeleton for my site and also used the leveluptuts tutorials as a basis. Unfortunately I'm not clear what you're trying to do but you can look at my site mylingerie-buntingford.co.uk to see how I did things and that might give you some pointers. I suspect I'm not using the latest version of skeleton so I don't know how that might change things.

Comment: Thanks for your response Pedro. My main concern was that in order for my header to be the full width of the page it was exceeding the 960px Skeleton max width.
It seems like your site is the same thought so maybe it is not a big deal.

Comment: Ah! I suspect you'd need to have your own container that was 100% width for the header and have your own columns etc.